# Can I use user input from a header to auto-fill other headers?

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with ten different spreadsheets inside it.  Each spreadsheet has a header that follows this format: "Project Name - Name of Spreadsheet - Revision Date:".

For instance, example spreadsheet headers should look like this:

```
"Test Project - Form 1 - Revision Date: "
"Test Project - Form 2 - Revision Date: "
"Test Project - Form 3 - Revision Date: "
```

And so on..

I would like to accommodate the user by only making them type the "Project Name" one time, and then it would auto-fill the rest of the headers with that value.  I know it can be done quite easily with cells, but I'm not very experienced with Excel.  Can this be done with headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the header which can only be seen in the Layout View and the Print Preview, that cannot be set using simple excel functions. You should do it in a macro.

If you store the project name in the cell A1, and the revision date in the cell B1, then you could place a button to the same sheet. The text of the button could be "Fill Headers", and the macro that it would run is this code:

```
Sub FillHeaders()

    For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If wSheet.Name <> "Cover Page" Then

            wSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = _
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & " - " & _
                wSheet.Name & " - Revision date: " & _
                ActiveSheet.Range("B1")

        End If

    Next wSheet

End Sub
```

This will go through all sheets (except the one named "Cover Page") and set the center headers to the text you need. Since ActiveWorksheet is the one where you pushed the button, therefore the A1 and B1 cells from *that* sheet will be used in the header text.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked wonderfully.  Is there any way to format the text using VB or would this have to be manually done?

Comment: You can format it using the formatting codes listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225426(v=office.12).aspx). The formatting code should stand before the text. For example to make it bold, the first row of the code must be changed to this: `wSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B" & _`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is my first time using VBA.  It's interesting.  One last question, is there a way to skip the first worksheet in the workbook, or add an if statement that checks the worksheet's name?  I have a cover page named "Cover Page" that I don't want to apply the header to.

Answer (score 1):

Use an input cell for the user to type in the project name, then name that cell, say, "Project_Name".

Next, for each header in your spreadsheets, put in the following formula:

```
= Project_Name & " - Form XX - Revision Date: "
```

(Obviously, changing "XX" for the Form Number)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely makes sense.  However, when I try this, it only places the code snippet as text as my page header.  Do formulas work in page headers?  I'm sorry I didn't clarify in my original post that I am indeed looking to automatically insert the Project_Name into a page header, rather than a column header.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood your question